# Python to create a find-replace dictionary from a word vba macro

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, dictionary, find-replace

***I have a very big macro***

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "asa"
        .Replacement.Text = "fsa"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "oriented"
        .Replacement.Text = "das"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ampere"
        .Replacement.Text = "^sasd"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "wattage"
        .Replacement.Text = "watts"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "balanced dit"
        .Replacement.Text = "BD"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Opthamologist"
        .Replacement.Text = "Eyes"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "goot health"
        .Replacement.Text = "good health"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
```

***I want to make a find replace dictionary from this vba macro***

```
dictionary = {"asa":"fsa",
              "oriented":"das",
              "ampere":"^sasd",
              "wattage":"watts",
              "balanced dit":"BD",
              "Opthamologist":"Eyes",
              "goot health":"good health",}
```

***the whole vba macro should be converted to this dictionary.***

***the words from .text and .replacement text should be made in to a dictionary.***

I need a python code to take the words from .TEXT and .Replacement Text and make a dictionary to

"TEXT":"ReplacementText"

I hope I have explained my problem very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open('source.txt', 'r') as file:
    inputText = file.readlines()

myDict = {}
for line in range(len(inputText)):
    # Have a Text line
    if inputText[line].lstrip().startswith('.Text'):
        # Get the key with regular expression
        key = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line]).group(1)
        value = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line + 1]).group(1)
        myDict[key] = value
print(myDict)
```

Output:

```
{'asa': 'fsa', 'oriented': 'das', 'ampere': '^sasd', 'wattage': 'watts', 'balanced dit': 'BD', 'Opthamologist': 'Eyes', 'goot health': 'good health'}
```

Comment: value = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line + 1]).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 1):

use a regex to get everything inside quotes. This will fetch key and value pairs of the wished output. Get all keys and values by slice with step of size 2.

```
import re

text = # from file

regex = r'"([^"]+)"'

matches = re.findall(regex, text)

out = dict(zip(matches[::2], matches[1::2]))
```