# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
import re

with open('Macros.txt', 'r') as file:
    inputText = file.readlines()

myDict = {}
for line in range(len(inputText)):
    # Have a Text line
    if inputText[line].lstrip().startswith('.Text'):
        # Get the key with regular expression
        key = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line]).group(1)
        value = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line + 1]).group(1)
        myDict[key] = value
print(myDict)
```

Why is this error returning ?

```
value = re.search('"(.+?)"', inputText[line + 1]).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

For more details:

[Python to create a find-replace dictionary from a word vba macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517126/python-to-create-a-find-replace-dictionary-from-a-word-vba-macro)

Comment: This is because sometimes the `search` method returns None when the pattern is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), `re.search()` returns `None` when the matching fails.